# Parsing a pattern like log4j

Tags: java

I have been looking around for a while in search of a parser that works similarly to how log4j's does and I could extend and modify.

Essentially I wish to create my own LoggingEvent-like class which I can just throw into a Parser initialized with a pattern that follows log4j's structure and it would just return a message String that uses my LoggingEvent-like class' attributes to replace the different '%' literals.

Is there something like that around? As simple and configurable as that? Or do I have to build the Parser myself?

EDIT:

What I want is something that would allow me to do something like this:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        AmazingSpecificPatternParser aspp = new AmazingSpecificPatternParser(String pattern);
        LoggingEventLikeObject lelo = ... //initialize lelo
        String parsedObject = aspp.parse(logginEventLikeObject);
        System.out.println(parsedObject);
    }
}
```

Where if pattern is "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p (%t) %c{1} - %m%n" then parsedObject would be 2015-02-24 10:10:15,876 INFO (main) ErrorThrower - "This was a great idea"

EDIT2:

How come this link:

[java regular expression for parsing log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056376/java-regular-expression-for-parsing-log-file)

answers my question? There's no reference to the formatting style used by log4j and it expects it to be solved using regex which is not the same format as log4j so I end up having to explain to the users that they have to create a regex pattern, not the log4j pattern...

I would like an explanation instead of a simple dismissal of my question, please.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056376/java-regular-expression-for-parsing-log-file and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083827/parsing-log4j-log-file-using-regular-expression

Comment: @Mike This doesn't ask for regex parsing of the pattern string, and I wouldn't use regex for it (that's going to make escaping difficult, and any qualifiers on the patterns will quickly complicate things).

Comment: Those are about log4j usage but I don't want to use log4j. What I want is a log4j-like parser... So I can just pass a pattern and an Object and it would just spit it formatted the way I want it to based on those...

Comment: log4j is open source.  get the source and take what you want.

Comment: I was going to do that but the source is really intrincate and all the formatting is tightly tied to the LoggingEvent class which I have no interest of using or extending since the way it works is quite different to what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 5, you can make use of the `String Formatter` class
when writing your statements and build your own.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Or just simply extend Log4J's classes... The question that comes to mind is what needs do you have that are not handled by the standard Log4J  classes?

Comment: I have some Database Objects that contain Audit information and I want to log them in a file... Since this is going to be used by other programmers I wish to allow for some degree of configuration and am trying to use a format that would be familiar for them... ergo log4j